# discord.py embed.fields.2.value: This field is required

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have a problem and I can´t fix it.
I'm trying to back an embed in which some information is displayed in the Rolle isn´t working

```py
if message.content.startswith("!userinfo"):
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    if len(args) == 2:
        member: Member = discord.utils.find(
            lambda m: args[1] in m.name, message.guild.members)
        if member:
            myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Userinfo für {}".format(member.name),
                                  description=" für den User {}".format(
                                      member.mention),
                                  color=0x22a7f0)
            myEmbed.add_field(name="Server beigetreten", value=member.joined_at.strftime(
                "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)
            myEmbed.add_field(name="Server beigetreten", value=member.created_at.strftime(
                "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), inline=True)

            rollen = " "
            for role in member.roles:
                if not role.is_default():
                    rollen += "{} \r\n".format(role.mention)
                if rollen:
                    myEmbed.add_field(
                        name="Rollen", value=rollen, inline=True)
                myEmbed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
                myEmbed.set_footer(text="Ich bin ein Kek")
                await message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Error:

> discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
> In embed.fields.2.value: This field is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is quite self-explanatory. The value of `Field 2` is empty, and it's not allowed to be. You just gave it `" "` as value, which isn't enough. Leading & trailing spaces are stripped out, so it becomes an empty string (`""`), which leaves the field empty.

If you want a field without any content, use `\u200b` ("zero width space") & it'll appear empty.

```py
myEmbed.add_field(name="Rollen", value="\u200b", inline=True)
```